# Flutter Hooks Fetching Data using useEffect - setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-hooks

Currently exploring functional_widgets and flutter_hooks. Having same idea with reactjs I'm fetching data with the following code.

```dart
@hwidget
Widget homeScreen(BuildContext context) {
  TodoListProvider model = Provider.of<TodoListProvider>(context);
  useEffect(() {
    print('effect');
    model.fetchList();
    return () => {};
  }, []);
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: _buildAppbar(context, model),
    bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNav(context, model),
    floatingActionButton: _buildFloatingAction(context),
    body: PageTransitionSwitcher(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      reverse: model.reverse,
      transitionBuilder: (
        Widget child,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      ) {
        return SharedAxisTransition(
          child: child,
          animation: animation,
          secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
          transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
        );
      },
      child: _getCurrentTab(model.currentIndex),
    ),
  );
}
```

I don't think this is the right way since it's throwing an error.[image]

Comment: `return () => {}` probably doesn't mean what you think it means.  You're returning a function that returns an empty Map when called.  I *think* you meant `return ()  {}`.  Remember, it's arrow or body block.  Not both. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue with:

```dart
  useEffect(() {
    model.fetchList();
  }, []);
```

is that `fetchList` is called synchronously inside build and modify an ancestor widget, which is not good.

You can wrap the `fetchList` call in a microtask:

```dart
  useEffect(() {
    Future.microtask(() => model.fetchList());
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is old.  But I hope my answer can help someone.  I solved the problem by making the function call in the next frame

```
useEffect(() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      model.fetchList();
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have used `useEffect()` to make init calls in cubits, like so:

```
final cubit = useCubit<BooksListCubit>();
final state = useCubitBuilder<BooksListCubit, BooksListPageState>(cubit);

useEffect(
  () {
    cubit.init();
    return null;
  },
  [cubit],
);
```

More on this in my extensive [Flutter cubits + hooks + Hive tutorial](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580).